# MacOS VM does not boot after updating from 10.7.3 to 10.7.5

Tags: macos, vmware, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I had VMWare workstation 7.1 running **Mac OS X 10.7.3**. I used software update and updated it to **10.7.5**.

Now the OS does not boot up. The screen shows the logo of apple and a "busy" animation. But it never loads.

What is the solution to this problem?

Also, I repaired the disk using another virtual disk (i.e. I clicked on "Utilities", selected the disk and clicked on "**Repair disk**"). The report says: "**The volume Macintosh seems to be OK**". But, it still does not boot up. What do I do?

Please help!!

Comment: Boot in verbose mode to see the console output…

Comment: How do I boot in verbose mode? Is it a vmware setting or a mac os setting??

Comment: there are various virtualization problems with 10.7.5, look at an update from VMWare

Comment: I have searched a lot about this problem. I can't find any solution. It seems like the problem exists in VMWARE 8 too (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744304/mac-os-x-10-7-5-vmware-image-stucks-on-load?rq=1).

Comment: i have same problem if you find the solution then share it for other.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after upgrading from 10.7.3 to 10.7.5 (directly with Software Update) all startups take about 40 minutes (as ankur said).

Searching, I found a patch that fixed the boot [here](http://howifixed.it/vmware-mac-os-x-updating-from-10-7-x-to-10-7-5/)

Comment: Thanks. I started using newest version of the OS which did not give any boot related issues.